# What is push repository URL?

Tags: git, bitbucket, weblate

I try configure Weblate for automatic pushing tranlate changes and need explanation and example: what is push repository url?

By example if is my repostory
https://bitbucket.org/username/repo/
https url is
https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git

but this does not work in weblate.

Excerpt from Weblate  documentation
"Repository push URL
Repository URL used for pushing, this is completely optional and push support will be disabled when this is empty."

https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/admin/projects.html#component

Answer (score 5):

HTTPS url requires password while push. Try git url like -

```
git@bitbucket.org:username/repositoryname.git
```

It will work. You will have to add public key also.

Comment: Indeed Weblate currently does not support HTTP authentication, I've adjusted docs to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

For checking you git push URL, You can run the below command.

```
git remote -v
```

From here you will get the fetch and push url. Also if the repository is present on bitbucket you have to provide access permissions so that the changes gets pushed to weblate server.

Please check the settings at bitbucket for key based access permission.